# How to clone a Case as a child case with particular record type

Tags: lightning, community, salesforce1-app, case-object, urlfor

I am trying to create a clone as a child case with different record type but when I clone it it it taking parent case's record type.

my code is:

`/{!Case.Id}/e?clone=1&cas5=CAR&cas28={!Case.CaseNumber}&RecordType=0126F000001749hQAA&retURL={!Case.Id}`

also I tried `{!URLFOR($Action.Case.Clone, Case.Id, [RecordType='0126F000001749'])}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:-

```
/{!Case.Id}/e?clone=1&cas5=CAR&cas28={!Case.CaseNumber}&RecordType=0126F000001749hQAA&ent=Case&retURL={!Case.Id}
```

You missed the entity, i.e **&ent=Case**

> This paramater defines on which object you are working. Basicallly ent
>   stands for Entity- means object in salesforce (either standard or
>   custom). For example, when you click new opportunity link, it redrects
>   to
>   https://cs##.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity&...
>   where ent equals to Opportunity defines that we are going to select
>   record type of Opportunity object

Now, you will be able to Clone with default record type. Hope it helps you.

**Update:-**

1. Url hack is not officially supported by salesforce
2. It does not works in Lightning and salesforce mobile app.

**Description**

In classic, the requirement of cloning record via custom button and to perform edit operation to various fields on the cloned version is achieved by listing the ID of the fields to edit and the new values in the button's URL. 
For Lightning, currently there's no out of the box functionality available.

**Resolution**

There is no direct out of box functionality to do this using custom button and quick actions. You can use the example process outlined below to achieve the same in Lightning via customization.

1. Create a Lightning component. Make use of force:hasRecordId interface. This enables the component to be assigned the ID of the current record.
2. In the controller part, clone the record and change some values accordingly.
3. Display a screen with changed fields, and save and cancel button.
4. Use that Lightning component to be called on the click of a "Quick Action".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried given link too but no luck. Following link works fine in classic but not in lightning /{!Case.Id}/e?retURL={!Case.Id}&RecordType=0126F000001749l&clone=1&cas5=CAR&cas28={!Case.CaseNumber}

Comment: I have updated my answer. Url hack generally does not work in lightning.You may be lucky to get it work sometimes. You need to move on quick action in Lightning.

Comment: Can you please help me in quick action that how can I use existing case as parent case

Comment: i have updated my answer. You need to create custom component and follow the steps in answer.

Comment: Or you can create visualforce page too and use it as quickaction, but better to go with lightning component

Comment: Hey sanket thanks for your valuable time and help. I created it using quick action. Thanks. One more question is it possible to show lightning component as List button under Related Case tab.

Comment: In the related list, you can override the existing button for classic, Lightning and salesforce1 app. or, You can add the custom to the related list, What you need is to edit layout and then configure related list to add the custom button by clicking on related list properties.